# Enabling web in existing Flutter project gets error "Binding has not yet been initialized."

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I'm attempting to web-enable a Flutter project that is a couple of years old. I've gone through all of the steps I can find online, but when I attempt to Run Debugging for Chrome I get the error below.

I am aware that the error 'Binding has not yet been initialized' is caused by not calling WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized(), however, when I run on Chrome it never gets to my main(), therefore, I never get chance to call ensureInitialized().

What's happening is the debugger launches Chrome and creates a Tab that displays my app name, but my flutter code never gets called.

I would appreciate any help in solving this problem.

```
The "instance" getter on the ServicesBinding binding mixin is only available once that binding has been initialized.
Typically, this is done by calling "WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" or "runApp()" (the latter calls the former). Typically this call is done in the "void main()" method. The "ensureInitialized" method is idempotent; calling it multiple times is not harmful. After calling that method, the "instance" getter will return the binding.
In a test, one can call "TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized()" as the first line in the test's "main()" method to initialize the binding.
If ServicesBinding is a custom binding mixin, there must also be a custom binding class, like WidgetsFlutterBinding, but that mixes in the selected binding, and that is the class that must be constructed before using the "instance" getter.
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (errors.dart:266:49)
    at binding.dart:284:9
    at BindingBase.checkInstance (binding.dart:365:14)
    at get instance [as instance] (binding.dart:54:54)
    at platform_channel.MethodChannel.new.setMethodCallHandler (platform_channel.dart:519:51)
    at DtmfPlugin.registerWith (dtmf_web.dart:14:12)
    at Object.registerPlugins (web_plugin_registrant.dart:36:14)
    at web_entrypoint.dart:27:24
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:339:39)
    at initialization.dart:73:24
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at _engine.AppBootstrap.new.<anonymous> (initialization.dart:71:16)
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.callMethod (operations.dart:398:10)
    at Object.dsend (operations.dart:402:5)
    at _engine.AppBootstrap.new.<anonymous> (app_bootstrap.dart:72:22)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at runBody (async_patch.dart:84:54)
    at Object._async [as async] (async_patch.dart:123:5)
    at app_bootstrap.dart:70:25
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:339:39)
    at ret (js_patch.dart:413:11)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at app_bootstrap.dart:68:14
    at Object._checkAndCall (operations.dart:334:14)
    at Object.dcall (operations.dart:339:39)
    at Object.ret [as runApp] (js_patch.dart:413:11)
    at (index):53:26
```

````dart
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.10, on macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 3.3.10 on channel stable at /Users/keithblack/GitHub/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 135454af32 (2 weeks ago), 2022-12-15 07:36:55 -0800
    • Engine revision 3316dd8728
    • Dart version 2.18.6
    • DevTools version 2.15.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/keithblack/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-33, build-tools 30.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 13F100
    • CocoaPods version 1.11.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6915495)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.74.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.56.0

[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    • iPhone 8 (mobile)      • 6F91BC53-6CE3-4AE1-89CF-D076DABD5430 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5 (simulator)
    • iPhone 12 Pro (mobile) • 9CCAD0CA-0B66-42E9-B554-535A45FD5877 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-15-5 (simulator)
    • macOS (desktop)        • macos                                • darwin-x64     • macOS 12.5.1 21G83 darwin-x64
    • Chrome (web)           • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 108.0.5359.124

[✓] HTTP Host Availability
    • All required HTTP hosts are available

• No issues found!```
````